# All from WAMP works except phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

I've got WAMP running on localhost port 80 as is the default. Everything was working until I installed TeamViewer Sot I disabled TeamViewer's use of port 80 and still no dice.

Apache still runs, the databases are still accessible (local websites still work), and I can navigate to `http://localhost/` just fine to see the default WAMP home screen, but `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` returns:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
```

Any ideas why just phpMyAdmin is inaccessible?

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled and re-installed WAMP and all is back to normal. I wish I knew what caused the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced almost the same thing and I thought it had to do with an external application like Skype or so, but I actually think wamp did som kind of automatic update that went wrong.  In the access-error logs I found that js-files were missing and I know that I did not erase any such files...

When I tried to access phpMyAdmin only the logo showed up. **I solved it by upgrading the phpMyAdmin** following a thread I found on wampserver forum:
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,59446,59454

(**The post:** Re: How to Upgrade phpMyAdmin? Where do you keep the detailed instruction?
Posted by: c2dan (---.15-1.cable.virginmedia.com)
Date: January 25, 2010 07:42PM)